# PHP command line fails with no error on full path

Tags: php, linux, cron, command-line-interface

Basically it's this

```
>php /full/path/to/php/file.php
```

Fails with no output, warning, error anywhere in any log. Seems like it runs fine, but it actually does not run. However, changing working directory to /full/path/to/file/php

```
> php file.php
```

Works as expected.

What is special about this php script is that it:

1. reads files from an NFS mount
2. parses contents
3. loads file contents into a local MySQL table
4. renames files it has successfully loaded.

   Operating system is CentOS 6.

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: Does `file.php` use absolute or relative paths to the files it needs  / renames?

Comment: yes. relative path. Rationale: seems when I started this weeks ago, full path wasn't working at all. Added a symlink to the NFS mount dir in the php working directory and things started working the way I wanted.

Comment: so add some basic debugging. even `<?php echo 'here i am!'` at the start of the script to see if anything's actually happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your edit, in your script, you should change to the correct directory. You can do that using using [`chdir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php):

```
chdir('/full/path/to/php/');
```

Now php is probably looking for the symlink in the wrong place.

You can use `getcwd()` to see in which directory you are.